# C# Compound Interest Calculator Using a Loop (Error CS0103)

Tags: c#

I want to create a Compound Interest Calculator in C# using two classes in different namespaces but can't for the life of me figure out why I keep getting errors.

PSA I am a beginner, I know this code probably looks awful, but please be kind.

Here is CompoundTest.cs

```cs
namespace CompoundTest
{
       class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CompoundClass newprogram = new CompoundClass();

            Console.Write("\nPlease enter the initial balance for your account: ");
            double balance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.Write("\nPlease enter the annual interest rate: ");
            double interestRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()) / 100;


            Console.Write("\nHow many years will you acrue interest? ");
            double annualAmount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine($"Your balance after {annualAmount} years is {accountBalance:C}");


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is Compound.cs

```
using System;

namespace Compound
{
    public class CompoundClass
    {

        private double balance;
        public int value { get; private set; }

        public CompoundClass()
        {
            Balance = value;
        }


        public double Balance
        {
            get
            {
                return balance;
            }
            private set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    balance = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Rate(double interestRate)
        {
          interestRate = value / 100;

        }


        public void Years(double annualAmount)
        {

         annualAmount = value * 12;


        }


        public void addMethod(double accountBalance)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < annualAmount + 1; i++)
            {
                accountBalance = balance * Math.Pow(1 + interestRate / annualAmount, annualAmount * i);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
CS0103 C# The name '..' does not exist in the current context - in the public void addMethod(double accountBalance) method
```

Comment: Sometimes the parsing trips up so badly, teh compiler can not even tell you were the error is anymore.

Comment: Unless I'm missing it, I don't see you calling any method in your `CompoundClass` - you _seem_ to be trying to get some value that _isn't_ returned in `addMethod` (`void`)

Comment: Some general Advice: You want to avoid code like in that for loop. You have 1 function call and 4 math operations in that one piece of code. If there is an issue with anything, the compiler can only point roughly at that line. Try to split such things up, using temporary, local variables.  | Also addMethod has no return value, and as Balance is not a out parameter nothing will actually change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing any data on the CompoundClass, the method

```
public void Rate(double interestRate)
{
    interestRate = value / 100;
}
```

only operates on the input parameter interestrate inside the functions scope, after that the result of the calculation is lost

If you want to reuse a variable on the entire lifetime of the CompoundClass, then define it as a member variable like:

```
private double _interestRate
```

and change your function to

```
public void Rate()
{
    _interestRate = value / 100;
}
```

and for the annualAmount as well

```
private double _annualAmount;

public void Years()
{
  _annualAmount = value * 12;
}
```

and your calculation to

```
public double addMethod(double accountBalance)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < annualAmount + 1; i++)
    {
                accountBalance = balance * Math.Pow(1 + _interestRate / _annualAmount, _annualAmount * i);
    }

    return accountBalance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more then one thing wrong with this code. And I am honestly not sure if I even got anything close to your problem yet.

```
using System;

namespace Compound
{
    public class CompoundClass
    {

        private double balance;
        public int value { get; private set; }

        public CompoundClass()
        {   
            //Balance with a big B is nowhere in context
            Balance = value;
        }


        public double Balance
        {
            get
            {
                return balance;
            }
            private set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    balance = value;
                }
            }
        }

        //As remarked by somebody else, this function does nothing. Without return or out parameter, interest rate will stay at nothing.
        public void Rate(double interestRate)
        {
          interestRate = value / 100;

        }

        //The naming of this variable is bad. Did you mean "Amoung of Months"?
        //Also as someone else pointed out, you do not return or otherwise persist this value
        public void Years(double annualAmount)
        {

         annualAmount = value * 12;


        }
        //Method does not return anything.
        //accountBalance is a local value and will not persist
        public void addMethod(double accountBalance)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < annualAmount + 1; i++)
            {
                //Avoid putting that much stuff into 1 line. It really messes with your ability to debug
                //1-2 operations + 1 assignment to a temporary variable per line
                //Anything more and you will have serious issues debugging this
                accountBalance = balance * Math.Pow(1 + interestRate / annualAmount, annualAmount * i);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generally the variables this works with should be either purely parameters (wich means it should be a static class with static functions) or mostly class variables. You have both things mixed all over the place.